# UnsupportedOperationException - The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

when starting my hibernate/spring application I am getting the following exception:

```
815  [main] WARN  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator  - HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
846  [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
871  [main] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder  - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
886  [main] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator  - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
891  [main] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
1153 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
1153 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
1153 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.testApp.gui.startGUI.main(startGUI.java:22)
```

However, when looking in the `persistance.xml` you can see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.detection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I guess the file is rightly configured, for a hibernate and hsql connection. On the other hand there is my `applicationContext.xml`, which is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.testApp"
        annotation-config="true" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="mainWindow" class="com.limitCalculator.gui.MainWindow" />

</beans>
```

My question is, why am I getting this exception? Any recommendations, what is wrongly configured? I personally think that my `applicationContext.xml` is not right, however I am not sure where the error is.

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Where is database definition means database name?

Comment: @Sunny thx for your answer! What do you specifically mean?

Comment: Have you define database name in xml file?

Comment: @Sunny Thx! Nope, I do not use any hibernate.cfg.xml file. I tried to define everything in my `persistance.xml` file. Can`t I do that? How to fix this error? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Kare You need to define a Data Source. In your current configuration there is none

Comment: @geoand Ok, get it thx for your answer! Honestly, I do not know how to do that, therefore any recommendations what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the following changes to your configuration:

In `applicationContext.xml`

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL"> <!-- Use this shortcut since you are using HSQL -->
</jdbc:embedded-database>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

To get the `jdbc` namespece to work in `applicationContext.xml` you need to 
add

`xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd"`

and

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd`

to the `xsi:schemaLocation`

And then change your `persistence.xml` to

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.detection" value="class, hbm" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I am getting for `<jdbc:embedded-database ...` the error: `The prefix "jdbc" for element "jdbc:embedded-database" is not bound.` Any recommendations for that?